# Replace String in Java

Tags: java

Basically my `dataHandler` content should be a string referencing the id of the soap attachment but my Stub puts the base64string based on the DataHandler object passed to the Stub instead.

How can I "hack" into the body of the message before sending?

`env.getBody().toString().replaceAll(pattern, "<dataHandler>cid:" + cid + "</dataHandler")` does exactly what I want but `env.getBody().setText` doesn't set the text of the body**

```
// create a message context
_messageContext = new org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext();

// Modified
// Attachment
String cid = _messageContext.addAttachment(dispatchDocumentRequest8.getDataDescription().getDataHandler());

// create SOAP envelope with that payload
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope env = null;


env = toEnvelope(getFactory(_operationClient.getOptions().getSoapVersionURI()),
    dispatchDocumentRequest8,
    optimizeContent(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("com.test",
    "dispatchDocument")));

// Modified
String pattern = "(?s)<dataHandler[^>]*>.*?</dataHandler>";

env.getBody().setText(env.getBody().toString().replaceAll(pattern, " 
<dataHandler>cid:" + cid + "</dataHandler"));
```

Comment: Is there an `env.setBody` ? EDIT: actually I think it's `env.addBody`

Comment: Also depending on what versions etc you are using, possibly `env.getBody().setTextContent`

Comment: @Matt there is no setTextContent nor addBody. Axiom 1.2.12

Comment: SOAPEnvelope is an interface, what is the concrete type you are getting back from the 'toEnvelope' method? You could try get your string, do your replace, and create a new envelope

Answer (score 0):

[Never](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/750510) [ever](https://medium.com/thecyberfibre/stop-parsing-x-html-with-regular-expression-2cf13215b411) parse XML / HTML / YML / any-other-ML using regular expressions!

Use appropriate parsers. There are [three different parsers for XML](https://dzone.com/articles/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and): DOM, SAX, StAX. But in your case you already have XML via `getBody()`!

```
final Document doc = env.getBody().extractContentAsDocument();
final NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("dataHandler")

// Do stuff like
IntStream.range(0, nodes.getLength()).mapToObj(nodes::item).forEach(item->{
    item.setNodeValue(…);
});
```

Comment: The method extractContentAsDocument() is undefined for the type SOAPBody

Comment: this is axiom SOAPBody not javax.soap don't forget

Comment: Probably `getChildElements` will give you an iterator of nodes that you can traverse and change values?